# A way to get open positions in bingx api

Tags: python, rest, exchange-server, cloudflare

I want to receive information about open transactions.
But I can't get all open trades at once.
And I have to send the request for each currency and because of this I am limited even though the number of my requests is almost one per second.
Can anyone help?

I used the documents of this exchange to get open positions
But the problem is that it doesn't list all the open transactions, and you have to send a request for each currency individually, and this limits me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get your open positions you should use the following endpoint:  [/openApi/swap/v2/trade/allOrders](https://bingx-api.github.io/docs/#/swapV2/trade-api.html#User%27s%20History%20Orders)  You can then filter the data to find positions that are opened but never closed.

If you are looking for your pending orders then you should use this endpoint instead:  [/openApi/swap/v2/trade/order](https://bingx-api.github.io/docs/#/swapV2/trade-api.html#Query%20Order)

If you are having trouble with implementing the API, you can take a look at my implementation ([py-bingx](https://github.com/amirinsight/py-bingx)).